# LEFT OUTER JOIN Increasing SUM. How to Prevent This?

Tags: t-sql, ssms

Simplified version of query below, but fundamental gist of it:

```
WITH ClientSpend AS
    (
        SELECT
            c.ClientName
            , CONVERT(INT, (ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN e.Type = 1 THEN e.Dollars ELSE 0 END), 0))) AS 1_Dollars
            , CONVERT(INT, (ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN e.Type = 2 THEN e.Dollars ELSE 0 END), 0))) AS 2_Dollars
            -- There's a bunch more of these for different 'Types'
        FROM Expense e WITH(NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN Client c WITH(NOLOCK)
                ON c.ClientID = e.ClientID
        GROUP BY c.ClientName
    )
SELECT
    ClientName
    , 1_Dollars
    , 2_Dollars
FROM ClientSpend
GROUP BY ClientName
```

Type 2 has its own Expense table which breaks out into more granular detail that I need for a final CASE/SUM line in the CTE SELECT.

I tried testing the above query with a LEFT JOIN to this [ExpenseType2] table ON as many indexes as I can, and I noticed that the SUM on the 2_Dollars is higher when doing this. I'm assuming it's making multiple records even though I'm not selecting anything from the [ExpenseType2] table.

How do I prevent this?

Thanks,

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a sub query? Or a simple select statement? Or you may need to assert more information with sample data.

```
SELECT first_name, 1_Dollars, 2_Dollars FROM  
(
    SELECT
        c.ClientName
        , CONVERT(INT, (ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN e.Type = 1 THEN e.Dollars ELSE 0 END), 0))) AS 1_Dollars
        , CONVERT(INT, (ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN e.Type = 2 THEN e.Dollars ELSE 0 END), 0))) AS 2_Dollars
        -- There's a bunch more of these for different 'Types'
    FROM Expense e WITH(NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN Client c WITH(NOLOCK)
            ON c.ClientID = e.ClientID
    GROUP BY c.ClientName
) a
```